# Sort pandas dataframe by date in day/month/year format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to parse data from a csv file, sort them by date and write the sorted dataframe in a new csv file.

Say we have a very simple csv file with date entries following the pattern **day/month/year**:

```
Date,Reference
15/11/2020,'001'
02/11/2020,'002'
10/11/2020,'003'
26/11/2020,'004'
23/10/2020,'005'
```

I read the csv into a Pandas dataframe. When I attempt to order the dataframe based on the dates in **ascending order** *I expect the data to be ordered as follows*:

```
23/10/2020,'005'
02/11/2020,'002'
10/11/2020,'003'
15/11/2020,'001'
26/11/2020,'004'
```

Sadly, this is not what I get.

If I attempt to **convert the `date` to `datetime` and then sort**, then some date entries are converted to the **month/day/year** (e.g. 2020-10-23 instead of 2020-23-10) which messes up the ordering:

```
      date     reference
2020-02-11         '002'
2020-10-11         '003'
2020-10-23         '005'
2020-11-15         '001'
2020-11-26         '004'
```

If I **sort without converting to `datetime`**, then the ordering is also wrong:

```
      date     reference
02/11/2020         '002'
10/11/2020         '003'
15/11/2020         '001'
23/10/2020         '005'
26/11/2020         '004'
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('order_dates.csv',
                 header=0,
                 names=['date', 'reference'],
                 dayfirst=True)

df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
# df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.sort_val

df.sort_values(by='date', ascending=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
df.to_csv('sorted.csv')
```

Why is sorting by date so hard? Can someone explain why the above sorting attempts fail?
Ideally, I would like the `sorted.csv` to have the date entries in the **day/month/year** format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.loc[:,'date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'date'], format='%d/%m-%Y')
```

Comment: This works! But it the dates are formatted as year-month-day (e.g. 2020-10-23). Could we modify it so that it uses the day/month/year format instead?

Comment: Try `.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')` Here is a link to the python strftime character references: https://strftime.org/

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to specify the `datetime` format while reading the csv file. To do this try that:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', parse_dates=['Date'],infer_datetime_format='%d/%m/%Y').sort_values(by='Date')
```

This will read your dates from csv and give you this output where dates are sorted.

```
        Date Reference
4 2020-10-23      '005
1 2020-11-02     '002'
2 2020-11-10     '003'
0 2020-11-15     '001'
3 2020-11-26     '004'
```

What's left now is to simply change the formatting to the desired one

```
>>> df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Keep in mind however that this will change the `Date` back to `string` (object)

```
>>> df
         Date Reference
4  23/10/2020      '005
1  02/11/2020     '002'
2  10/11/2020     '003'
0  15/11/2020     '001'
3  26/11/2020     '004'

>>> df.dtypes
Date         object
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you use different format arguments in the `datetime` and in the `strftime`? Also, if you could shed some light into why my attempts fail to sort that would be very helpful.

Comment: Your answer by the way does not solve the issue; it sorts it as follows: 02/11/2020, 10/11/2020, 15/11/2020, 23/10/2020, 26/11/2020 where the 4th entry is mis-sorted.

Comment: Hi, just seen this. I will edit my answer as I may have been in a rush when answering.

Comment: Did that do the job for you?